# PHP Personality Insights

Tags: php, curl, ibm-cloud, personality-insights

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();
     $post_args = array('body' => $data );
     $header_args = array(
         'Content-Type: text/plain',
         'Accept: application/json'
     );
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_args);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"'xxx':'xxx'");
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v2/profile");
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

     $result = curl_exec($curl);

     curl_close($curl);

     $decoded = json_decode($result, true);
     ?>
```

I want to use IBM Bluemix Personality Insights with php curl and I am getting this error: `Undefined variable: data` What am I missing? How should I set up this variable, how should I pass the text that I want to have analyzed?

Answer (score 1):

In this php code what is `$data` variable you just assign to `$post_args['body']`. i think you are using in post filed so just try if you get somthing from url than

```
$post_args = array('body' => $_POST['data']) ;
```

or just set some value if you sending to the url

```
$data = 'Your real data which you want to send in url  ' ; than use in array .
```

Comment: i looked over the internet and there are many files missing.why ibm hasnt provided with a php example of personality insights,is still unclear

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and there is no err now.The problem is that it is not displaying anything,in the html.how?

Comment: try to `var_dump($result)`

Comment: It mean your `curl_exec()` function is failing [http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php]

Comment: the 4-th example that you sent me,that crated from a month ago,check this page:https://github.com/eciggaar/watsonpi-php/blob/master/watson_pi.php

Comment: I am stuck at://$watsonPi = $services_json["<servicename>"][0]["credentials"];    ?? what is service name?// Curl initialization to make REST call to Watson service // Get textarea field from POST request
// Set post arguments for call

Comment: you try this file which in cheatsheet  (https://github.com/eciggaar/watsonpi-php/blob/master/cheatsheet/watsonpi-snippet.php) this explain more better than this file . Secondly  your `index.html` file have form which have textarea tag they  are sending this to `watson_pi.php` so now your data variable is `$data = $_POST['txtarea']` .  My suggestion is you can try replace file in  action attribute in `index.html` with `watsonpi-snippet.php` try this file

Comment: the raw text starts from $data....I remove the $data = $_POST["txtarea"]; and replace it with $data='some text'; still it echos raw php starting from $data and below

Comment: What is it  showin when you `var_dump($result)` now

Comment: i havent inserted it since it has an echo itself,but its surprising why the code doesnt run full,up to $data then all php is printed like text

Comment: i finay got it running,you need to change the index.html to .php and it echos null now.

Comment: there is no code of php in `index.html` so why we have  to  change but it works good for you

Comment: the file runs now but it echos null and I dont know why?I even try to set the $data='some string'; and it still echos null.Seriosly I dont understand where the heck the problem is...